# How to structure javascript objects, while not getting 'undefined' is not a function errors?

Tags: javascript

If I have a javascript class that runs some initialization code, it seems logical to put this code at the top, and any methods at the bottom of the class. The problem is, if the initialization code contains a method call, I get a 'undefined' is not a function error. I imagine because the method is defined after the method call. How do people normally structure javascript classes to avoid this? Do they put all the initialization code at the end of the class? For example:

```
var class = function() {
   this.start();
   this.start = function() {
      alert('foo');
   };
};
var object = new class();
```

causes an error, while:

```
var class = function() {
   this.start = function() {
      alert('foo');
   };
   this.start();
};
var object = new class();
```

does not. what would be considered a good structure for a javascript object like this?

Comment: I get `class is a reserved identifier` in Firebug: http://jsfiddle.net/ATeMb/ I'm guessing this isn't the error you're referring to, though.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, I realized the example code uses reserved words. Switch class with foo and object with bar to try it yourself.

Comment: Updated with [`class` changed to `cls`](http://jsfiddle.net/ATeMb/1/), now I get a `TypeError: this.start is not a function` error. (I realized that may have been the case after I posted the initial comment.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes, that is the error my original post is complaining about.

Comment: My own personal preference is to always put the function definitions at the top, right below the list of variables I have for that scope and the object properties. This is just how I like to organize it, though.

Comment: Look up information on variable hoisting in JavaScript as to why a `this.` "variable" is not hoisted similarly.

Comment: not sure hoisting matters in this case since only declarations are hoisted anyways. i'm not trying to figure out the "why", I am trying to figure out what people do in this type of case.

Comment: What about using an `init()` private function to organize your code at the top, as you're wanting to do? It seems you can as long as you `init.apply(this, arguments)` when you do call it internally, and that when called it has to be after all of the functions that `init()` references internally, which probably means it's best to put it at the bottom. It's a compromise, but more intuitive I think. Note that I'm not sure if there are any downsides to this approach. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gF6sY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var class = function() {
   this.start();

};
class.prototype.start = function() {
      alert('foo');
   };

var object = new class();
```

now you can mess around with start as much as you want in the constructor. but dont use the keyword class as it is a reserved word.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do

```
// create a "namespace"
var com = com || {};
com.domain = com.domain || {};

// add "class" defintion
com.domain.MyClass = function(){
    var privateFields = {};
    var publicFields = {};

    privateFields.myFunction = function(){
        // do something
    }

    publicFields.initialize = function(){ 
        privateFields.myFunction();
    }
    return publicFields;
}

var myClass = new com.domain.MyClass();
myClass.initialize();
```

of course, you could just make `initialize();` "private" and run it before `return publicFields;`

Answer (score 0):

I actually work a lot with structures like this:

```
var foo = function() {
    // Actual construction code...
    start();            // <-- doesn't make a difference if functions are
    privateMethod();    //     public or private!

    // ---------------------------------

    function start() {
        // ... whatever ...
    };

    function privateMethod() {
        // ... whatever ...
    };

    // ---------------------------------

    // Add all public methods to the object (if start() was only used internally
    // just don't assign it to the object and it's private)
    this.start = start;
};
```

Comment: not clear why you do `t.start = start;`, instead of just defining the method as public to begin with by doing `this.start = function()...`?

Comment: I'm defining ALL methods (public and private) at the top - those that should be accessible from the outside (public) get assigned to the object in an extra step. That way, it doesn't make a difference whether a method is public or private. In other terms: `start();` works inside the class regardless of it's visibility from the outside.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right. I got confused, sorry. I've edited my code, it now reflects the version where you have the functions at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I like http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ where I feel much more programing OOP.

```
var myClass = Class.extend({
  init: function () {
    this.foo();
  },

  foo: function () {
    alert("foo");
  }
});

new myClass();
```

Comment: I like this. If I am not mistaken, this requires that we include the base "Class" definition found in the blog post? How can you create non-public variables with this method of class writing?

Comment: for single time just use var inside methods. Private members or methods javascript object can't hold.

Comment: if I use the examples in the original post, I can have private methods and variables.

Comment: Are you sure? I think you can use "private" methods only for constructor.

Comment: Each method defined within the constructor inherits the constructor's scope, so each of these methods (public or private) can call any other of the object's methods and access any of the constructors variables (this makes these variables/methods private). If you were to use prototype to add methods to the class outside of the constructors scope, they would not be able to call other methods or access other variables of the object unless they were set as public (using `this.blah =` instead of `var blah =`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider making `start` a method on `class`'s prototype.  This has the bonus of saving memory since all instances of `class` can share the same `start`, instead of creating a new `start` function for each instance.

```
var class = function() {
   this.start();
};

class.prototype.start = function() {
   alert('foo');
};

var object = new class();
```